# java.io.FilePermission - access denied

Tags: java

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.security.AccessControlException: acc ess denied (java.io.FilePermission write)

i am getting the above error when i tried to write into a file.

what i need to do kindly help out...

i am running an applet application...

Comment: Have you tried signing your applet?

Comment: Post the relevant code (and maybe accept some answers?)

Answer (score 6):

Applets are by default denied from accessing the client's file I/O. You need to sign your applet or edit the [policy files](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem).

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know Applets cannot write to files as this would be a security violation.  You can expressly grant the file-writing permission to the JVM to enable this but i think that would be a really bad idea because your users would be allowing you to write whatever you wanted to their disk via the web.  Why does your applet want to write to a file?

Answer (score 1):

Is your applet signed? Non signed applets can't access files.
See here: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
 fos=AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
    public  FileOutputStream run() {
      return new FileOutputStream(f1);
    }
  });
```

or edit file "`java.policy`" add 
permission `java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read,write"`;